# Password protected URL loads very slowly on latest version of chrome and with protractor

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I have a password protected URL, it opens up on chrome(latest version) very slowly.

```
https://username:password@demo.xyz.com
```

Google Chrome version is - **85.0.4183.121**

Actually the URL I'm opening from a protractor test case as below.

```
browser.get("https://username:password@demo.xyz.com");
```

Even if I try to open a manual way still takes to much time to load about 2 min, But If I open the URL without a username and password then it loads immediately.

Any suggestions?

Comment: login in the app after the page is loaded